# $G_n$ group of invertible matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. Show that there is a path connecting $A\in G_n$ and and an orthogonal matrix

Tags: general-topology

Let $G_n$ be the  group of all invertible matrices $n\times n$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Given $A\in G_n$, show that  there exists a path in $G_n$ which begins at $A$ and ends at an orthogonal matrix.

I was thinking about of writing $A=PO$ as a product between a symmetric positive definite matrix and an orthogonal matrix. Then, considering
 a path $C(\lambda) = \lambda PO + (1-\lambda)O = \lambda A + (1-\lambda)AP^{-1}$, i should be able to argue, using determinants, that the path $C$ is enterely into $G_n$. But i'm not so clear how to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted the path
$$[0,1] \ni \lambda \mapsto ((1-\lambda)P + \lambda I) \cdot O$$ where you use the fact that the set of symmetric positive definite matrices is convex.

Answer (score 0):

That's a sound idea: recall that every positive definite matrix is $\exp(C)$ where $C$ is symmetric.

Another idea. Write $A=NO$ where $O$ is orthogonal
and $N$ is triangular with strictly positive diagonal (Gram-Schmidt process). The line segment joining $I$ to $N$ consists of invertible matrices.